# Flutter Riverpod mutating issue

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, riverpod

i am developing some board game

**Code:**

```
static List<Ball> calculateAllMoveCordsForHardMove(int wichBoard) {
    final List<Ball> moveList =
       navigatorKey.currentContext!.read(gameStatusProvider).moves;

    print(
        'Cord(${moveList[0].cord?.x.toString()}, ${moveList[0].cord?.y.toString()})');

    for (int i = 0; i < moveList.length; i++) {
      final boardNumber = moveList[i].wichBoard ?? 0;
      if (boardNumber == wichBoard) {
        final cord = moveList[i].cord ?? Cord(0, 0);

        final newCord = nextCord(cord, boardNumber);//just returuns a cord
        moveList[i].cord = newCord;
      }
    }

    final moves2 =
        navigatorKey.currentContext!.read(gameStatusProvider).moves;

    print(
        'Cord(${moves2[0].cord?.x.toString()}, ${moves2[0].cord?.y.toString()})');

    return moves;
  }
```

**Output:**

```
flutter: Cord(0, 2)
flutter: Cord(0, 0)
```

i think .read returns a mutable reference

when i change the moveList also changes the provider value

I don't want to change the provider value, thats all.

thanks.

Comment: Share more context for your question to be clearer. A good template is having
- The question
- A brief explanation
- The code (all the concerned parts)
- What you have done.

Comment: Your state appears to be mutable.  And you're mutating it directly, without calling functions on your notifier to do so.  This is heading for disaster.  Don't do that.  Consider the result of .read or .watch as read-only, and add methods to your notifier to update the value instead.

Comment: What I want to do is calculate the next move and figure out who will win. For this, I want to take the current moves and understand what will happen next.
I don't want my changes on the moveList to change the provider.
Also, I call the provider in a class, not in a widget.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want my changes on the moveList to change the provider

It doesn't trigger a change to the provider, but if you use mutable types in models, you can change what's referenced inside the provider.

In your code, `moveList[i].cord = newCord;` changes the object referenced in the list, which is the state of your provider.

Short answer is, don't do that. This change will not be noticed by the provider, and it will not notify its listeners, until next rebuild of the provider.

You should avoid mutating state underneath the provider this way. To assist with creating immutable objects, consider packages like [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed), [built_value](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value) .etc. but generally you have to be aware of collections in either case. There are other packages that can help with immutable collections as well.